# Reference request: Algorithms on Turing Machines

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, reference-request

Is there a good survey or some papers with algorithms in the Turing machine model? I know the paper STRING-MATCHING AND OTHER PRODUCTS contains Turing Machine version of KMP. Are there any other such papers?

Comment: There are tons of papers on algorithms on the Turing machine model, would be helpful to know if you are looking for anything more specific.

Comment: I am looking for a couple of pointers where one could start learning about them. A survey would be preferable.